# Nokia C01 Plus - only 3 icons allowed in Quick Settings/Swipe Down Icons

Tags: android-11, quick-settings, android-go, nokia

This is Nokia C01 Plus running Android version 11 (as per what's shown in About Phone).

Quick Settings (swipe down icons) - when you swipe down from the top of the screen, you get these icons which allow you to toggle several settings (WiFi, Airplane Mode, Mobile Data, Flashlight, Bluetooth, Hotspot, Data Saver, Battery Saver, etc).

On all Android phones I have used, there are multiple rows of these icons visible when you swipe down. But on this phone, I can just have 1 row with 3 icons - most icons are available when I try to edit the swipe-down icons list, but I can only have 3 in total available at all times.

[image]

<sup>Image courtesy of [91Mobiles](https://www.91mobiles.com/nokia-c01-plus-price-in-india?ty=gallery)</sup>

Is there a way to have more?

Comment: Might be worth noting that this phone runs on Android Go which might also affect the UI behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not work without root dependant upon multiple factors.  Download a settings .db editor such as [SetEdit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=by4a.setedit22), then follow the instructions provided in the app's description in it's Play market description to grant it additional permissions through ADB.  Open the app and search for any keys that begin with or contain "sysui_qs..."; these pertain to the QuickSetting tiles.  If you find a key for "sysui_qqs_count", try modifying the value to, e.g., "5" and see if that works.  Otherwise, you can try straight ADB modifications (e.g., [here's](https://www.xda-developers.com/add-tiles-to-quick-settings-header-google-oneplus-sony-phones-no-root/) an XDA thread on the topic).  If it doesn't work, you might require root access.

EDIT: Instructions for ADB permissions:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I downloaded SelfEdit, but I don't see any instructions in playstore to grant additional permissions. I see lot of different settings categories in SelfEdit - but I don't see any which begin with sysui. Which category does it fall under?

Comment: Added a screenshot regarding the ADB instructions.  I would check `secure` table, but YMMV depending on make, device, or even carrier.